# Does Libinput require X/Wayland?

Tags: xorg, input, headless

In short: Is X.org a dependency of Libinput?

Rephrased, can libinput work standalone?

The question is mostly about hacking around with some input devices. I'm trying to route USB/PS1/Bluetooth input through a headless raspberry pi. I want this to be as generic as possible, while keeping my installation as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [manpages](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/libinput.1.html):

```
libinput  is  a  library  to  handle input devices and provides device detection and input
device event processing for most Wayland compositors  and  the  X.Org  xf86-input-libinput
driver.

The  libinput  tools  are  a  set  of  tools to debug, interface with and analyze data for
libinput. These tools create libinput contexts separate  from  that  of  the  compositor/X
server  and  cannot change settings in a running session.  See section COMMANDS for a list
of available commands.

libinput's API documentation and details on features and various high-level  concepts  are
available online at https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/

The man page for the X.Org xf86-input-libinput driver is libinput(4).
```

Comment: So to answer my question: no, it doesn't need X?

Comment: No it doesn't. You can look up dependencies on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libinput10).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much